# Resuse the connection pool created in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

The code is below

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import pool
try:
    postgreSQL_pool = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1, 20,user = "postgres",
                                              password = "pass@#29",
                                              host = "127.0.0.1",
                                              port = "5432",
                                              database = "postgres_db")
    if(postgreSQL_pool):
        print("Connection pool created successfully")

    # Use getconn() to Get Connection from connection pool
    ps_connection  = postgreSQL_pool.getconn()

    if(ps_connection):
        print("successfully recived connection from connection pool ")
        ps_cursor = ps_connection.cursor()
        ps_cursor.execute("select * from mobile")
        mobile_records = ps_cursor.fetchall()

        print ("Displaying rows from mobile table")
        for row in mobile_records:
            print (row)

        ps_cursor.close()

        #Use this method to release the connection object and send back to connection pool
        postgreSQL_pool.putconn(ps_connection)
        print("Put away a PostgreSQL connection")

except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error :
    print ("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)

finally:
    #closing database connection.
    # use closeall method to close all the active connection if you want to turn of the application
    if (postgreSQL_pool):
        postgreSQL_pool.closeall
```

So let say we have wrapped code in a function. similar way if we create another function as per code we need to create connection pool again..

I am  thinking it to don't close the connection pool and reuse it different function.

How can we find the existing pool and reuse it.

Thanks

Comment: if the pool must be reused by multiple methods, initialize it outside of the methods and pass the pool as variable... like

`def myfun(pg_pool, other_params):
    conn = pg_pool.getconn()
    ...
`

Comment: It will be multiple files so questions is how to know about existing connection pool

Comment: From Python perspective, the pool is an object which has properties, state, and external resources. So your question is: how to make `my_runtime_object` available everywhere in my project?  The answer is: in general case, you cannot. If your Python process terminates, the object simply disappears.